# Extract profile's field level security

Tags: profile, field-level-security

Is there a way to get a profile's field level security?
I tried an soql query for FieldPermissions object but it's based off of permission sets so if there's no permission set with at least read access on that field, it doesn't show up. However, I want all the fields on the profile itself.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Is it just for documentation purpose, or ts for business use case?

Comment: Want to turn it into excel sheet to use

Comment: Last time I did this, I wrote an Excel Macro. One API call to get all field names and generate columns/rows, then another to get the active fields, which populated the grid. It took a couple of days because I suck at VBScript, but overall wasn't too hard to accomplish. Sadly, I don't have the source for this any longer.

Answer (score 0):

All Profiles have child permissionSets which are the parents of their field permissions. These links have a very good diagram and sample queries:
[PermissionSet object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.208.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_permissionset.htm)
see also
[FieldPermission object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_fieldpermissions.htm)

Here is a sample query that delivers all the child field Permissions. You just need to add the Profile name or ID to the WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id,   SobjectType, Field ,ParentId , PermissionsEdit ,PermissionsRead,  Parent.IsOwnedByProfile,  Parent.Name,Parent.Profileid ,  Parent.Profile.Name
FROM FieldPermissions
WHERE Parent.IsOwnedByProfile = true
     AND Parent.AND Parent.ProfileId = '...your Id here'
LIMIT 100
```